# How do I troubleshoot a Silex application?

Tags: php, silex

I'm trying to do what I would think is the most basic thing and it is taking too much time.  I simply want my index file to point to or forward to another file.  I was originally doing this with a simple one liner.

```
require_once getcwd() . "/web/source/index.php";
```

Once I migrated to Silex I tried this:

```
$app->get('/', function($path) use($app) {
    return $app->sendFile('/web/source/index.php');
});
```

but there was no go.

When I go to my site I get a very descriptive "Whoops Something went wrong". How can I troubleshoot this?

Here is the full code with all the boilerplate:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->get('/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    // this works fine
    return ' test: '. $app->escape($name);
});

$app->get('/', function($path) use($app) {
    // this does not
    return $app->sendFile('/web/source/index.php');
});

$app->run();
```

Here are the [docs I'm using](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html)

Comment: Well....you could turn debugging on for starters.

Comment: `$app['debug'] = true;` - it's up

Comment: I assume you have a `.env` file in there somewhere, if you do, it may have another setting that overwrites the `$app['debug'] = true;` one.

Comment: Debugging is on and working.  I had to take out the $path variable, and now I got a new error - path not found.

Comment: `getcwd()` requires permission to actually work, hence, it's probably not giving you the full path. Although I fail to see it's necessity in the context you're using it. Some `$_SERVER` stuff should work fine too.

Comment: It works fine, you got the answer if you want to mark it.  `__DIR__` was needed, I don't know why.  I've also used `getcwd()`, but were a bit off topic now.  You answered the question in your first comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Eh, I suppose I should Imaginary internet points are the best.

Comment: That would be a great screen name - imaginary_internet_points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn debugging on by doing `$app['debug'] = true;`.

If you have a `.env` file, also make sure it's not overwriting your default setting.