# $app->sendFile works when in debug mode, fails otherwise

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have this route in my Silex router:

```
$app->get( "/route", function () use ( $app ) {
    $path = __DIR__ . "/../path/to/files/dir";
    $files=glob("$path/*.*");
    sort($files);
    $files = array_reverse($files);
    $newestFile = $files[0];
    $newestBasename = basename($newestFile);

    return $app
        ->sendFile( $newestFile )
        ->setContentDisposition( ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $newestBasename );
});
```

It's fairly straightforward, copied basically verbatim from [Silex' docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html). It works fine when I'm in debug mode; but, as soon as I turn off debug mode, it gives me a "Whoops, something went wrong" error message when I hit the route.

I've tried:

- Removing the `setContentDisposition` line.
- [Streaming the file](https://www.euperia.com/development/forcing-a-file-to-download-using-the-silex-php-framework/934) instead of using `sendFile`.
- Reading other people's questions about `sendFile` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373665/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-silex-application), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970440/how-to-implement-resumable-download-in-silex), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076738/how-to-return-an-image-to-an-https-request-with-php), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407994/what-is-the-difference-betweed-getcwd-and-dir)).

All to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

[ Note regarding `symfony` tag: I'm not using Symfony per-se, but included the tag since I am using the Symfony component `ResponseHeaderBag` as part of this route. ]

Comment: Did you try to clear the cache ?

Comment: @FavianIoelP Yes. Sometimes after taking it out of debug mode, I'd think it was fixed until I cleared the cache, at which point it would start displaying the error again.

Comment: Can you dig through the http server (or fpm) logs? That should reveal a bit more about the nature of error.